# How can I copy ML model's training results to specific folders

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have created a Machine Learning model that classify cats and dogs from a dogs vs cats database. It's a huge database. I apply this code:

```
predictions = model.predict(test, verbose=0)
for i in range(0,10):
    if predictions[i, 0] >= 0.5: 
        print('I am {:.2%} sure this is a Dog'.format(predictions[i][0]))
    else: 
        print('I am {:.2%} sure this is a Cat'.format(1-predictions[i][0]))

    plt.imshow(test[i])
    plt.show()
```

and it gives me output as a photo and a text like this:

```
(Cat photo from test dataset)
I am 100.00% sure this is a Cat
```

There isn't any problem till this point. As an another different example, it can show like this:

```
(Dog photo from test dataset)
I am 62.34% sure this is a Dog
```

So, my problem is, I would like to copy these photos to the files if it is bigger than %50 percent.

For example, If It says like this:

```
I am 100.00% sure this is a Cat
```

I want to copy this to cat folder. This folder doesn't exist before. If it say like this:

```
I am 62.34% sure this is a Dog
```

I want to copy this to dog folder. This folder doesn't exists before as well.

I am really stuck at this point. Any ideas? Thanks for all of your comments

Answer (score 0):

The two modules you can use to achieve this task are subprocess and os + shutil.

1. Using the subprocess module:

Assuming you have access to the original paths

```
import subprocess
make_dir = subprocess.Popen("mkdir dogs & mkdir cats", shell=True)
make_dir.wait()
if predictions[i, 0] >= 0.5:
    p = subprocess.Popen('cp {original_file_name} {new_path}'.format(original_file_name=original_file_name, new_path=new_path), shell=True)
    p.wait()
```

2. Using the Shuttle and OS Module

> ```
> import os, shutil
> os.mkdir('dogs')
> os.mkdir('cats')
> if predictions[i, 0] >= 0.5:
>     shutil.copyfile(original_file_name, new_path)
> ```

Comment: I can access to the original path But, the thing is, in original test folder there are too much cats and dogs images.It's too much,so that I cannot copy them with hand.Because there are not labeled.However, I wrote a code that,it can classify it as whether dog or cat with some percentage in code.So, according to that results. I want to copy the classified images to the separate files.Like 123.jpg We don't know anything about it If the code result says, It's %56 percent dog. I would like to copy them to the Dog folder.
Another example, if it says %70 cat, I would like to copy it to Cat folder.